# Mimic Sculpting Shader/Light setup for Render

Tags: shaders, sculpting

I'd like to recreate the shading that is going on in the Sculpting view for high-resolution render.
It seems to have a very specific light-setup and way of catching light
the soft specular, very thick black creases it creates and the almost solarized fill light (light blueish bottom-lighting)

[image: example]

Is there a Material out there that does this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, found it! Slightly different location in 2.8
[![Matcap in 2.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk8Au.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk8Au.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render it in Cycles or Eevee, you can use this setting which allows to render a matcap:

[image]

The principle is to project the faces normal into the camera space so that we can hit the matcap texture by centering the projection using the mapping node, as a matcap texture looks like this:

[image]

You can choose the shader: here diffuse is used, but so the rendering is affected by other lights and shadows. If you want to avoid that, use the emission shader.

Matcap textures available in Blender can be found in your Blender installation path in '2.80\datafiles\studiolights\matcap'.

You can also use *Workbench* render engine. But in this case, all objects will have the same rendering:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of **matcaps**. In 2.7x they're available after hitting <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D Viewport. See the image below:

[image]