# Recreate material from blender sculpt mode with nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor, sculpting, sculpt

When you are sculpting in blender sculpt mode you can switch between a number of different materials. one of them is a red clay like material, i would like to recreate this specific material using nodes. i have attempted to get something similar with the principled shader but to no sucess. could anybody instruct me how to do this? (attached picture depicts the material i am refering to).
[image: thumbnail from video by jayanam on youtube]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147846/mimic-sculpting-shader-light-setup-for-render/147854#147854

Comment: Thank you lemon, this is exactly what i was looking for.