# How to render this matcap in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I would like to render a material similar to this. been trying all day, but can't come close. I tried searching for a similar material online (like plastic or rubber) but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147846/mimic-sculpting-shader-light-setup-for-render/147854#147854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here's one of them:

[image]

The **Value** node determines the softness of the highlights.

[image]

Comment: i think he wont need the bump map in this case...

Comment: Just tested it out. worked amazingly. thank you!

Comment: Just one question, how do I get a smoother material (without the bump map). Would just deleting the 'noise texture' and 'bump' node work?

Comment: Yeah - just get rid of the bump node or set the strength to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Setting the bump node to 0 created some issues in the rendering. I went with deleting the noise texture and bump node: https://imgur.com/a/wtrywjh Is this the best set up?